# Why is the request culture not set before a view has been rendered?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

**Introduction**: I am currently using view localization in ASP.NET Core 2.1 for my views. As a `CultureProvider` I am using only `CookieRequestCultureProvider.`

Then I need to change the requested culture dynamically, so I am re-setting the cookie to a new value. However, I am struggling with an error, when right request culture is not chosen.

**Use case**: I have a route `/project/{city-name}` - action method `Project` with route parameter `city-name`. Each project can have different number of possible languages. So that when cookie in a project is set to a language which do not exist in another project, I need to re-set cookie to default value for the another project (these kind of information are stored in database).

So let's imagine the following scenario, you access to path `/project/krakow` then you set your language preferences to Polish language so the request culture is set to Polish. Then you decide to go to another project - `project/ostrava`, where the language preference Polish does not exist.

So I need to re-set cookie to default language for given project, so that view localization can select right `.resx` file.

However, If I do re-edit cookie, the right .resx file is not chosen even if the cookie has been set. Only page refresh is assuring that correct `.resx` file is chosen.

Why is this behavior happening? Why does not a cookie set before rendering a view?

For ensuring that the cookie will be set before rendering a view I created custom Middleware which reacts on path starting with /project. When I inspect cookie in debugger I see that cookie has been set. However, the change is notified only after page refreshing.

**Method for setting request culture** (abbreviated for code for clarity)

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string city)
 {

    if (HttpContext.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>().CanTrack)
    {
       Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1), Secure = true });
     }

     return RedirectToAction("Project", new { City = city }); 
  }
```

**Cookie middleware**

When I inspect debugger, I see that cookie is set correctly. Even in browser I see that change has been made.

```
public class CookieMiddleware
{
   private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

   public CookieMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
   {
       _next = next;
   }

   public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   {
       if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/project")))
       {
           var cityName = httpContext.Request.GetUri().Segments[2];
           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cityName))
           {
               var unitOfWork = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork)) as IUnitOfWork;
               var projectInfo = unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.GetProjectInfo(cityName);

               httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                      CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                      CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(projectInfo.DefaultLanguageCode.ToLower())),
                      new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1), Secure = true });
             }
         }
   return _next(httpContext);
}
```

Action method which is responsible for selecting view for project

```
  [HttpGet("/[action]/{city:required}")]
  public IActionResult Project(string city)
  {
       //HERE IN RQF I DO NOT DETECT THAT CHANGE HAS BEEN MADE.
       //ONLY WHEN I DO REFRESH OF A PAGE, I SEE CORRECT REQUEST CULTURE COOKIE
        var rqf = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
        return View();
  }
```

Order of registered middlewares:

Language cookie middleware is registered right after RequestLocalization. I tried even swap these two... without success.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseStaticFiles();
     app.UseCookiePolicy();
     app.UseRequestLocalization();
     app.UseCookieLanguageMiddleware();   // My cookie middleware
     app.UseMvc(routes =>
     {
          routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });
}
```

Comment: It probably depends where your middleware fits in the scheme of things (if it's registered first in the chain). By the way, you might want to look into using the Accept-Language header instead of managing this through cookies (at least as a way of selecting a default).

Comment: @John I made question update. However, thanks for tip for Accept-Language header. At least I can try it, it may help to fix the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are not writing cookies to the _response cookies_ of the request and attempting to read them from _request cookies_ within the same request?